# chromium navigation blocked

Tags: android, google-chrome, chromium

I have hyperlink on my mobile webpage that is supposed to open my app if the app is installed in the same Android phone.
The hyperlink is not done directly as described [here](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents) but through an intermediary URL (which magically redirects users to Play Store or iTunes store):

```
<a target="_blank" class="get-app-button" href="https://xxx.onelink.me/234129282?pid=Mobilesite&amp;c=SG_Smartbanner&amp;af_dp=xxx://brand::becca&amp;af_web_dp=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.xxx.sg%2F">
```

Logs:

```
01-25 17:16:59.628 W/cr_Chrome: Bad URI 'intent://brand::becca?af_deeplink=true&campaign=SG_Smartbanner&media_source=Mobilesite#Intent;scheme=xxx;package=com.xxx.digital;S.browser_fallback_url=market://details?id=com.xxx.digital&referrer=af_tranid%253DdfjL3z9mDvSLtimUWhv6lg%2526pid%253DMobilesite%2526c%253DSG_Smartbanner%2526af_dp%253Dxxx%253A//brand%253A%253Abecca;S.market_referrer=af_tranid%3DdfjL3z9mDvSLtimUWhv6lg%26pid%3DMobilesite%26c%3DSG_Smartbanner%26af_dp%3Dxxx%3A//brand%3A%3Abecca;end'
01-25 17:16:59.638 I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Navigation is blocked: intent://brand::becca?af_deeplink=true&campaign=SG_Smartbanner&media_source=Mobilesite#Intent;scheme=xxx;package=com.xxx.digital;S.browser_fallback_url=market://details?id=com.xxx.digital&referrer=af_tranid%253DdfjL3z9mDvSLtimUWhv6lg%2526pid%253DMobilesite%2526c%253DSG_Smartbanner%2526af_dp%253Dxxx%253A//brand%253A%253Abecca;S.market_referrer=af_tranid%3DdfjL3z9mDvSLtimUWhv6lg%26pid%3DMobilesite%26c%3DSG_Smartbanner%26af_dp%3Dxxx%3A//brand%3A%3Abecca;end", source: https://xxx.onelink.me/234129282?pid=Mobilesite&c=SG_Smartbanner&af_dp=xxx://brand::becca&af_web_dp=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.xxx.sg%2F (0)
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `target="_blank"` solved the problem